# Active Directory User isn't able to validate

Tags: c#, active-directory, network-programming

I'm trying to connect to Active Directory server to validate user with my system but when I'm trying to connect to the server, I get this error:

> Server could not be contacted

This is the code I'm using to validate the user:

```
var principalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain,  "LDAP://192.168.0.184/", "OU=St,DC=st,DC=un,DC=na");
var userValid = principalContext.ValidateCredentials(username, password);

if (userValid)
{
    result = true;
}
```

Please help me figure out how I can validate the user against AD and also tell me the meaning of `OU=St,DC=st,DC=un,DC=na`

Comment: The third parameter of your `PrincipalContext` constructor is the **container** inside Active Directory in which the connection is made - `OU=St,DC=st,DC=un,DC=na` stands for a domain `st.un.na`, and an organizational unit `St` inside that domain. This is one of the possible problems - if the user account doesn't exist *in that container*, but elsewhere - you might not get the response you're expecting.

Comment: But the main problem (I believe) is that you're saying you're connecting to a **domain**, which providing a **machine IP** - not sure if this will work. Can you try to use the **actual domain name** for your environment, e.g. `LDAP://yourcompany.com` or something like this, to establish the connection to Active Directory?

Comment: i understand your answer so can you please explain me little bit more how can write above parameter to connect with AD or how i can get  my actual domain name from environment

Comment: The error is very clear.. the server cannot be contacted. Google port, you should find it's 389. Run telnet client and telnet to port 389 on that server... telnet 192.168.0.184 389 and see if you get a response. If not, you might have a firewall blocking or an ip that is incorrect. To find your SOA record, open cmd prompt and run nslookup. Specify your domain name. You can also set record type to soa